# How to filter data by conditions after Groupby in Python

Tags: pandas-groupby

I have data like this:

| price | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021/01/01 | 9:00 |
| 200 | 2021/01/02 | 9:00 |
| 112 | 2021/01/01 | 9:01 |
| 223 | 2021/01/02 | 9:02 |
| 1145 | 2021/01/01 | 9:02 |
| 2214 | 2021/01/02 | 9:03 |
| 11 | 2021/01/01 | 9:03 |
| 20 | 2021/01/02 | 9:10 |

I need to get 3 values from each day. The price at 9:00, the price at 18:00 (There are more data), and a random value from that day except 9:00 and 18:00. 9:00 is not the start time, and 18:00 is not the end time.

I know I should use groupby for example: df.groupby('Date')['price'] But I don't know how to use conditions to filter data after groupby.

Because I need to use these data of every day, after I filter these data, I also need to get these data. The expected answer is like [100,112,200] (100 is price at 9:00,112 is the random price, 200 is the price at 18:00)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add some data to your dataframe:

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO

csv = StringIO("""price,date,time
100,2021/01/01,9:00
200,2021/01/02,9:00
1800,2021/01/01,18:00
2800,2021/01/02,18:00
112,2021/01/01,9:01
223,2021/01/02,9:02
1145,2021/01/01,9:02
2214,2021/01/02,9:03
11,2021/01/01,9:03
20,2021/01/02,9:10
1145,2021/01/01,19:02
2214,2021/01/02,11:03
11,2021/01/01,19:03
20,2021/01/02,3:10""")

df = pandas.read_csv(csv, index_col=None)
```

I know the next part is a mess and I hate pandas
But I hope you find the answer and got the idea.
just run codes :)

```
grouped = df.groupby('date')
except18_9 = grouped.apply(lambda x: x[(x['time'] != '18:00')&(x['time'] != '9:00')]).reset_index(drop=True)
part1 = except18_9.groupby('date').sample(n=1)
part2 = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.loc[(x['time'] == '18:00') | (x['time'] == '9:00')]).reset_index(drop=True)
pandas.concat([part1,part2]).sort_values(['date','time'])
```

final result is like this:

[image: results]

Comment: maybe because you filter columns. instead of using this df.groupby('Date')['price']
use df.groupby('Date').
maybe it is helpful if you just run my code with my data and then compare with yourself.